# Legend is too long

Tags: plotting, legending

I've a problem with the legend of my graph. I've customized the graphs of my papers in an acceptable way for the a lot of journals. But this time I've two problem:

1. Is there a simple way to write the names of compounds? I've written them by hand!
2. The real problem is: the legend is too long. I tried to move it on the right or below the graph, but it is not acceptable.

Is there a way to divide the legend in columns or another pretty way that I do not know?

```
 data =
   {
     {{0.388677, 9.93}, {0.352228, 8.57}}, 
     {{0.53975, 15.65}, {0.53114, 15.4}, {0.522233, 15.}, 
      {0.521965, 14.92}, {0.513295, 14.7}}, 
     {{0.442124, 16.96}, {0.420902, 15.89}}, {{0.500897, 21.9}}, 
     {{0.5643, 26.66}}, {{0.573449, 16.97}}, 
     {{0.557509, 16.}, {0.54885, 15.84}}, 
     {{0.660017, 19.6}}, {{0.61177, 37.5}}, {{0.363762, 11.09}}, 
     {{0.355667, 11.5}}, {{0.423394, 16.65}}, {{0.285016, 9.44}}, 
     {{0.583312, 15.85}}, {{0.310173, 8.18}}, {{0.485398, 14.26}}, 
     {{0.467278, 14.06}}, {{0.413139, 15.73}}, {{0.569744, 16.1}}, 
     {{0.469172, 16.75}}, {{0.401343, 13.68}}, {{0.405889, 15.52}}, 
     {{0.410936, 14.54}}
   };

 compoundName = {"Decamethylcyclopentasiloxane", 
 "Decamethyltetrasiloxane", "Dimethyldichlorosilane", 
 "Dimethyldimethoxysilane", "Diphenyldichlorosilane", 
 "Dodecamethylcyclohexasiloxane", "Dodecamethylpentasiloxane", 
 "Eicosamethylnonasiloxane", "Gamma-aminopropyltriethoxysilane", 
 "Hexamethylcyclotrisiloxane", "Hexamethyldisilazane", 
 "Methyl Dichlorosilane", "Methyl Trichlorosilane", 
 "Octadecamethyloctasiloxane", "Octamethylcyclotetrasiloxane", 
 "Octamethyltrisiloxane", "Silane", "Tetrachlorosilane", 
 "Tetradecamethylhexasiloxane", "Tetraethoxysilane", 
 "Tetraethyl Silane", "Trichlorosilane", "Trimethylchlorosilane"};

 colours = {Red, Blue, Green, Darker[LightBlue], Black, LightBlue, 
 Cyan, Gray, Magenta, Brown, Orange, Pink, Purple, Darker[Purple], 
 Darker[Red], Yellow, Darker[Yellow], Darker[Cyan], Darker[Magenta],
 Darker[Brown], Darker[Pink], Darker[Purple], Darker[Green]};

 par1 = 13;
 par2 = 20;

 plot = ListPlot[data, 
   PlotMarkers -> {
     {"●", par2}, {"▲", par2}, 
     {"△", par2}, {"▽", par2}, 
     {"▼", par2}, {"◀", par2}, 
     {"▶", par2}, {"○", par2}, 
     {"◆", par2}, {"■", par2}, 
     {"★", par2}, {"□", par2}, 
     {"◇", par2}, {"*", par2}, 
     {"▯", par2}, {"\[DottedSquare]", par2}, 
     {"\[GraySquare]", par2}, {"\[CheckedBox]", par2}, 
     {"✶", par2}, {"⧏", par2}, 
     {"⊴", par2}, {"⧐", par2}, 
     {"⊵", par2}}, 
   PlotStyle -> colours, 
   ImageSize -> 500, 
   PlotLegends -> 
     Placed[{
       Style["Decamethylcyclopentasiloxane", par1], 
       Style["Decamethyltetrasiloxane", par1], 
       Style["Dimethyldichlorosilane", par1], 
       Style["Dimethyldimethoxysilane", par1], 
       Style["Diphenyldichlorosilane", par1], 
       Style["Dodecamethylcyclohexasiloxane", par1], 
       Style["Dodecamethylpentasiloxane", par1], 
       Style["Eicosamethylnonasiloxane", par1], 
       Style["Gamma-aminopropyltriethoxysilane", par1], 
       Style["Hexamethylcyclotrisiloxane", par1], 
       Style["Hexamethyldisilazane", par1], 
       Style["Methyl Trichlorosilane", par1], 
       Style["Methyl Trichlorosilane", par1], 
       Style["Octadecamethyloctasiloxane", par1], 
       Style["Octamethyltrisiloxane", par1], 
       Style["Silane", par1], 
       Style["Tetrachlorosilane", par1], 
       Style["Tetradecamethylhexasiloxane", par1], 
       Style["Tetraethoxysilane", par1], 
       Style["Tetraethyl Silane", par1], 
       Style["Trichlorosilane", par1],
       Style["Trimethylchlorosilane", par1]}, 
     Bottom], 
   Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
   FrameLabel -> 
     {Style["(1-Tr\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\()\), 
        StyleBox[\"B\",\nFontWeight->\"Plain\"]]\)", 18], 
      Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(σ\), \(exp\)]\)(mN·\  
        \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \(-1\)]\))", 
        18]}, 
   FrameStyle -> 15, 
   PlotRange -> All]
```

The effect is

[image]

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: I have seen many times in journals that in such cases the notations are given in a caption, rather than in a legend: "Red disk decamethylcyclo..., vertex-up filled triangle - decamethyltetra..." and so on. Another way may be in a journal with the two-column layout to make a figure with the width corresponding to two columns, its left panel being the figure itself, while its right one containing a table of legends.

Comment: It might be tidier to use structural formulae instead, e.g. $(\rm{Me}_3\rm{Si})_2\rm{NH}$ for hexamethyldisilazane.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, and yes!

1. You do need to enter all the names of the compounds once (as in the list `compoundName`), but after that, you can make *Mathematica* do the rest. As [Guess who it is](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/guess-who-it-is) suggests, you can make these names considerably more compact by specifying the chemical formulae. On a side note, *Mathematica* has access to curated chemical data via `ChemicalData`, which recognizes some of the chemicals, so you can retrieve some (but not, alas, all) of the formulae via

   ```
   formulae = ChemicalData[#, "Formula"] & /@ Interpreter["Chemical"] /@ compoundName
   ```

   Conversely, you could specify the formulae names as a string and use the `Interpreter` and `ChemicalData` to turn them into long-form names. For instance,

   ```
   ChemicalData[Interpreter["Chemical"]["C10H30O5Si5"], "Name"]
   ```

   > ```
   > "decamethylcyclopentasiloxane"
   > ```

   *Again, this will only work for some of your chemicals!*
2. You can specify a [`LegendLayout`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LegendLayout.html) to arrange the legend into rows or columns or whatnot. To do this, however, you do need to construct the legend explicitly, in this case with `PointLenged`. You can also add a panel or a frame to the legend using [`LegendFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LegendFunction.html).

---

**Example implementation**

Using your definitions of `data`, `compoundName` (I removed `"Methyl Dichlorosilane"`, since you didn't seem to use it), `colours`, `par2`, and `par2`,

```
markers = {
   "\[FilledCircle]", "\[FilledUpTriangle]", "\[EmptyUpTriangle]", "\[EmptyDownTriangle]", 
   "\[FilledDownTriangle]", "\[FilledLeftTriangle]", "\[FilledRightTriangle]", 
   "\[EmptyCircle]", "\[FilledDiamond]", "\[FilledSquare]", "\[FivePointedStar]", 
   "\[EmptySquare]", "\[EmptyDiamond]", "*", "\[EmptyRectangle]",  "\[DottedSquare]", 
   "\[GraySquare]", "\[CheckedBox]", "\[SixPointedStar]", "\[LeftTriangleBar]", 
   "\[LeftTriangleEqual]", "\[RightTriangleBar]", "\[RightTriangleEqual]"
  };

xlabel = "(1-Tr\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\()\), StyleBox[\"B\",\n\ FontWeight->\"Plain\"]]\)";
ylabel = "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Sigma]\), \(exp\)]\)(mN\[CenterDot]\ \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \(-1\)]\))";

plot = ListPlot[data,
  PlotMarkers -> Evaluate[{#, par2} & /@ markers],
  PlotStyle -> colours,
  ImageSize -> 500, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[
    PointLegend[
     colours,
     Style[#, par1] & /@ compoundName,
     LegendMarkers -> markers,
     LegendLayout -> {"Column", 2}],
    Right],
  Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
  FrameLabel -> {Style[xlabel, 18], Style[ylabel, 18]},
  FrameStyle -> 15,
  PlotRange -> All
  ]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: This is what I need. Thanks!!